# JavaScript function gives me (Uncaught ReferenceError: checkIfUserLogedIn is not defined) when called in HTML file in parcel dev server

Tags: javascript, parceljs

In my `admin.html` I called `checkIfUserLogedIn()` function when the page is loading

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Admin</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="checkIfUserLogedIn()">
        <h1>Admin Pannel</h1>
        <script src="./main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In `main.js` I imported my `checkIfUserLogedIn()` function from `checkUser.js` file.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import "firebase/auth";
import checkIfUserLogedIn from './checkUser';
```

`checkUser.js` file looks like this

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

export default function checkIfUserLogedIn() {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (user) {
        console.log(user)
    } else {
        console.log("user loged out")
    }
}
```

This is the `index.html` file entry point of the project

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sign In</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="form-container">
        <h1>Sign In</h1>
        <form method="post" id="signin-form">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="signin-email" placeholder="Email" required="true"> <br>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="signin-password" placeholder="Password" required="true"> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Sing In" class="btn">
        </form>
        
        <p><a href="./signup.html">Create New Account</a></p>
        <p><a href="./admin.html">Create New Account</a></p>
    </div>
    

    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to call `checkIfUserLogedIn()` function when the `admin.html` file is loading but I give an `Uncaught ReferenceError: checkIfUserLogedIn is not defined` error.

Comment: Remove the <body> attribute and in your main script, add `window.addEventListener("load", checkIfUserLogedIn);`

Comment: I want to run that function only when admin.html file loading

Comment: Right, then do `<body class="admin">` in admin.html and check `document.body.classList.contains("admin")` first

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem. Thanks to [chris-g](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g)

I added "admin" class to the admin.html page body. Then in my main.js file, I checked if the body has a class called "admin" if it has then added a load event listener.

```
if(document.body.classList.contains('admin')) {
        window.addEventListener('load', checkIfUserLogedIn)
}
```